# Android: Why does View background draw in editor but not in app?

Tags: java, android, view

I have an Android project with an xml file representing a row for an Adapter.

This row has a coloured View on the left hand side.

For some reason the View renders correctly in the graphical editor in Eclipse but not when I run it on a device.

The View draws at the correct size but there's no blue background like the editor has.

---

I've noticed when I dump the UI hierarchy that the View nodes aren't in the hierarchy.

If I break on binding the views in the adapter, I can see that mMeasuredHeight is correct but mMeasuredWidth is 0. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental.

---

Attached are screenshots and the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_header_accent"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/blue_primary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_small"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_small"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_cancel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view_header_accent"
        android:text="Brad"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/grid_small"
        android:text="Active"
        android:textColor="#80000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_small"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot from graphical editor in Eclipse:

[image: Screenshot from editor]

Screenshot from device:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

The issue is because the top level view is a RelativeLayout with wrap_content as the height.

Combine this with the child having a layout_height of match_parent and the measured height for the coloured child View ends up getting calculated to 0.

The workaround unfortunately is to set a fixed height for the row or optionally specify the top and bottom alignment of the coloured view to match other child views.

The final View looks like this:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view_header_accent"
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_subtitle"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_title"
    android:background="@color/blue_primary" />
```